# How to automate copy paste task from chrome to csv in macbook?

Tags: applescript, automator, google-chrome, automation, chrome-extensions

I am trying to automate the task in chrome. The task involves these steps:

1. Open a website
2. Open the network tab in developer tools
3. Scroll to the end of the infinite loading page
4. Copy the first payload from one of the website's APIs from the network tab (or copy the request as curl )
5. Paste the result into a txt file and save it

I have to repeat this task 20-30 times.

Right now, I am manually scrolling the page and copying the API's payload. What are the options to automate the process?

Few things I have thought to give a try including PyAutoGUI (Python) and Macbook's automator. Is there any better way to do this task?

Comment: Might be easier to scrap the web page directly from python.

Comment: Also check for web scraping on Stack Overflow.